# clariion troubleshooting

Tags: clariion

First of all thanks to Sim and Quack for the response ( sorry, I frittered a little as I 'm a newbie here) .Hence I 'm editing it and making it more clariion  oriented .
Secondly, I 've a question ...
If one of the HBAs in the server  is not visible to the storage even if navisphere , powerpath and Navi Cli 're installed what could be the reason ?

Would appreciate if some one can elaborate it .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have asked for a fair bit of information here. Maybe reword the question with some more specifics and then start to build it up into an overall Troubleshooting CLARiiON section. Your question about fabric management may need to be in another question altogether and be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: indeed, this is more suited to a discussion forum.  this site is for questions, but this is a little broad.  i agree with Sim, consider editing this question to be more clariion-admin-issues centric, and open another post for your fabric management question.

Comment: Does the HBA show up in powerpath? If not does it should up in your OSs device manager?

Comment: HBA does not show up in powerpath.However, it's showing up in my OSs device manager..

Comment: Is there a prob with the Ip address of the navisphere installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point have you registered at [EMC Powerlink](http://powerlink.emc.com/) yet? There is a lot of great information there.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for physcal problems between the SAN and your server (replace cabling with a known good ones, try a differet port on the switch, replace HBA as a last resort as you will have to reconfigure the HBA's address).  I had a similar issue with a CX3-10 last week that turned out to be a bad SFP on the SAN switch.

This was working at one point right?  or is this a new setup?

Comment: This is a completely new set up..cable looks fine ,even i 've tried a different  port on switch.The HBAs 're visible in the OSs device manager,but not to the storage..

Comment: Have you setup the SAN switch zoning?